Tabular classification with neural network (fastai) : Expected floating point type for target with class probabilities, got Char
As it is described in the tabular chapter of FastAI book, I tried to apply deep learning to tabular data. I used the same workflow as in the book.
to_nn = TabularPandas(df_nn, [Categorify, Normalize], cat_nn, cont_nn, y_names=dep_var, splits=RandomSplitter(valid_pct=0.2)(range_of(df_nn)))

dls = to_nn.dataloaders(batch_size=2)

learn = tabular_learner(dls, layers=[200, 100], n_out=1, loss_func=F.cross_entropy, metrics=accuracy)
learn.lr_find()

I get : Expected floating point type for target with class probabilities, got Char
I apply the following code to create batches then try to visualize them. The values seem correct (only numbers)
_, xb, yb = dls.one_batch()
yb = yb.float()
print("Input batch shape:", xb.shape)
print("Target batch shape:", yb.shape)
print("Target batch type:", yb.dtype)

I get :
Input batch shape: torch.Size([2, 5])
Target batch shape: torch.Size([2, 1])
Target batch type: torch.float32

Which is what I want to have !
